# vue3 js component :is not changing component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a component which gathers data from an API. The data brought back from the API is an array with details in. One of the values in the array is the type of component which should be rendered, all other data is passed through to the component.
I'm trying to render the correct component based of the value brought back from the database, but it is sadly not working.
I'm new to Vue but had it working in vue2 but would like it to work in Vue 3 using the composition API.

this is my component code which I want to replace:

```
<component :is="question.type" :propdata="question" />
```

When viewed within the browser this is what is actually displayed, but doesn't use the SelectInput component:

```
<selectinput :propdata="question"></selectinput>
```

SelectInput is a component with my directory, and works as intended if I hard code the `:is` value, like below:

```
<component :is="SelectInput" propdata="question" />
```

my full component which calls the `component` component and swaps components:

```
<template>
    <div class="item-group section-wrap">
        <div v-bind:key="question.guid" class='component-wrap'>
            <div class="component-container">
                <!-- working -->
                <component :is="SelectInput" :propData="question" />
                <!-- not working -->
                <component v-bind:is="question.type" :propData="question" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    import { defineProps, toRefs } from 'vue';

    import SelectInput from "./SelectInput";
    import TextareaInput from "./TextareaInput";

    const props = defineProps({
        question: Object,
    });

    const { question } = toRefs(props);

</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `question.type`?

Comment: check the value of `question.type` with `{{ question.type }}`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out that because I'm using `script setup` the components aren't named so the `component` component doesn't know which component to render.

so, i created an object with the components and a reference to the component:

```
    const components = {
        'SelectInput': SelectInput,
        'TextareaInput': TextareaInput
    };
```

and another function which takes in the component i want to show and links it to the actual component:

```
    const component_type = (type) => components[type];
```

then in the template i call the function and the correct component is rendered:

```
<component v-bind:is="component_type(question.type)" :propData="question" />
```

complete fixed code:

```
<template>
    <div class="item-group section-wrap">
        <div v-bind:key="question.guid" class='component-wrap'>
            <div class="component-container">
                <!-- working -->
                <component v-bind:is="component_type(question.type)" :propData="question" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    import { defineProps, toRefs } from 'vue';

    import SelectInput from "./SelectInput";
    import TextareaInput from "./TextareaInput";

    const props = defineProps({
        question: Object,
    });

    const components = {
        'SelectInput': SelectInput,
        'TextareaInput': TextareaInput
    };

    const component_type = (type) => components[type];

    const { question } = toRefs(props);

</script>
```

Not too sure if this is the correct way of doing this but it now renders the correct component.

Comment: If the names used in `question.type` are equal to the fileName of the component, you may dynamically import the component, which would make the `const components` redundant. `const getComponent = (name) => import('path/to/typesFolder/' + name + '.vue');` and use it on `<component :is="getComponent(question.type)" />`

Comment: Dynamic imports result in `[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function.` not using dynamic imports, which doesn't matter as i will only have the components which are in the object works.

Answer (score 1):

In case that your Components filenames are equal to the type specifier on your question Object, then you could dynamically import them to save some code lines.

This would also result in better scalability since you don't have to touch this component anymore in case you create more types.

```
<template>
    <div class="item-group section-wrap">
        <div v-bind:key="question.guid" class='component-wrap'>
            <div class="component-container">
                <!-- working -->
                <component v-bind:is="getComponent(question.type)" :propData="question" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { defineProps, toRefs } from 'vue';

    const props = defineProps({
        question: Object,
    });
    // GIVEN THE question.types are equal to the fileNames of the components to render:
    const getComponent = (name) => import(`./${name}.vue`);

    const { question } = toRefs(props);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This makes sense and would help in scalability as you mentioned, plus with the project, there will be a lot more components being generated and if i don't have to go into this component and edit it, its a win for me!

Comment: This will also help as the project will have a few 'templates', different components with different styles which are stored in different directories. The value is saved within the store, and i'll be able to dynamically change the component path based on this value! Thank you again, you've solved two problems in one!

Comment: using this i get:  [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. i had to result to my way below to get the correct result. I wanted to use this way as i have another component doing something similar with dynamic file names but couldn't get it to work